# Changing contentInset of UIScrollview automatically animates contentOffset with delay

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Here is what I want to achieve:

I have a sort of form with multiple textFields encapsulated in UISCrollView. When starting editing the field, the goal is to set it above the keyboard.

In order for this to work:

- I'm changing scrollView's bottom contentInset to height of the keyboard in order to allow all content to be scrolled above it
- Calculating absolute frame of textField in screen and using this to calculate its way(**diff**) to move above the keyboard
- Animating contentOffset using the **diff**

***The problem is:***  setting contentInset triggers automatic adjastment of contentOffset with delay.

***The question is:*** how to disable this automatic behavior

```
    internal func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification)
    {
        let duration = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
        let curve = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
        let targetFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue


        self.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.scrollView.contentInset.top,
                                                        self.scrollView.contentInset.left,
                                                        targetFrame.size.height,
                                                        self.scrollView.contentInset.right)


        let apDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let absRect = self.currentSelectedField!.superview!.convert(self.currentSelectedField!.frame, to: apDelegate.window)
        if absRect.origin.y + absRect.size.height > targetFrame.origin.y
        {
            let diff = (absRect.origin.y + absRect.size.height) - targetFrame.origin.y

            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {

                self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: self.scrollView.contentOffset.x,
                                                        y: self.scrollView.contentOffset.y + diff)
            }, completion: { (done: Bool) in

            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not animate. You are already in an animation block when the notification arrives. Just change the inset. Do not change the offset, as the scroll view will do that automatically.

Comment: I tried this. The animation of insets comes with delay. If I'm doing this, how can I use animation duration and curve of the keyboard?

Comment: If you use a scroll view, you have to live with the automatic scrolling that it does to reveal the first responder. If you don’t like that, don’t use a scroll view, and move the text fields yourself.